# How to list available regions with Boto3 (Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

As AWS expands and adds new regions, I'd like to have my code automatically detect that. Currently, the "Select your region" is hard coded but I would like to parse the following for just the **RegionName**.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
regions = ec2.describe_regions()
print(regions)
```

My output is JSON like so:

> {'Regions': [{'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-south-1'}, {'Endpoint': 'ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'eu-west-1'}, {'Endpoint': 'ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com', 'RegionName': 'ap-southeast-1'}]}

I've trimmed off the repeating data and the ResponseMetadata for the sake of space.

How can I parse the RegionName into a list?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The following will return you the RegionName and Endpoint for each region.

```
# List all regions
client = boto3.client('ec2')
regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]
```

Comment: `client = boto3.client('ec2')` fails with the error "botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region."

Comment: There are multiple ways to set the region (aws has good doc for that) but you can get straight from `client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')`

Comment: how can i give multiple regions names ? can i give it in this way `client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-west-2' && 'us-west-1')` @FrédéricHenri

Comment: @vishal.k you cannot have a client that spans multiple region, you would need to create one client for each region you plan to work on

Comment: I also wanted to avoid making service calls (and to use the the ec2 client at all, since I wanted to know the regions for SSM specifically), but this turned out to be the only solution that worked, since other methods also listed *opt-in* regions (like `ap-east-1` or `me-south-1`), which resulted in an `UnrecognizedClientException` when I made subsequent boto calls targeting those regions.

Comment: This will give you the regions that boto3 knows about, not the regions that are actually enabled within the AWS account.

Comment: Use describe_regions(AllRegions=True) if you want to get all AWS regions, not only the ones enabled in your account.

Answer (score 51):

In addition to Frédéric's answer, you can also get known regions for each service without making any service calls. I will caution you, however, that since this is pulling from botocore's local models rather than hitting an endpoint, it will not always be exhaustive since you need to update botocore to update the list.

```
from boto3.session import Session

s = Session()
dynamodb_regions = s.get_available_regions('dynamodb')
```

Additionally, you are not restricted to the regions in this list. If you are using an older version of botocore you can still use new regions by specifying them. They just won't appear in this list.

Comment: This option was great for me - I needed to make something in a library that makes no service calls.  Thanks for the pointing out that distinction!

Comment: Just to add: `get_available_regions('ec2', 'aws-cn')` can get you China mainland regions. The same goes for gov regions.

Comment: This will give you the regions that boto3 knows about, not the regions that are actually enabled within the AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a usable list of regions that you can do further things with. The list of regions returned by `boto3.session.Session()` is only a partial answer because usually some regions returned are disabled in the given AWS account.

To get a usable list of regions, make a simple test call to each region to see if it's enabled or not.

The below code is shaped to loop over enabled regions in an account. The functions accept an optional `Credentials` argument, like the kind returned by [boto3 sts assume_role](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts/client/assume_role.html). The specific example below utilizes EC2 describe_vpcs, but could be easily adapted to check other services.

The downside to this method is that getting the list of regions in the AWS account usually takes about 20 seconds. Though this may be acceptable for your scenario.

```
import boto3

# Constants
empty_credentials = {"AccessKeyId":None, "SecretAccessKey":None, "SessionToken":None}


def get_enabled_regions(Credentials=empty_credentials):
    # Get available regions from boto3 sessions
    available_regions = boto3.session.Session().get_available_regions('ec2')
    enabled_regions = []
    for region in available_regions:
        try:
            # For each available region, do one small test call using an ec2 client.
            ec2_client = get_service_client("ec2", Credentials=Credentials, region=region)
            ec2_client.describe_vpcs(MaxResults=5)
            # If the call succeeds, the region is enabled, so add to enabled_regions list.
            enabled_regions.append(region)
        except Exception as e:
            # If there is an exception, it means the region is disabled in this account.
            continue
    return enabled_regions


def get_service_client(service, region=None, config=None, Credentials=empty_credentials):
    return boto3.client(service, region_name=region, config=config, aws_access_key_id=Credentials["AccessKeyId"],aws_secret_access_key=Credentials["SecretAccessKey"],aws_session_token=Credentials["SessionToken"])


regions = get_enabled_regions()
for region in regions:
    # Get a region specific client.
    ec2_client = get_service_client("ec2", region=region)
    # Do region specific stuff here. Don't forget to paginate or use NextTokens.
    print(ec2_client.describe_volumes())
```

Alternatively, you could try these other approaches too.

- [AWS EC2 Describe Regions API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/describe_regions.html), use a filter for opt-in-status. This is ec2 specific. Maybe that's OK for your use case.
- [AWS Account List Regions API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/account/client/list_regions.html), use the `RegionOptStatusContains`. In my experience though, the list returned can contain disabled regions regardless of the filter you provide.