# InvalidLocationConstraint creating a bucket in af-south-1 (Cape Town) region using node.js aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am getting a `InvalidLocationConstraint: The specified location-constraint is not valid` error when trying to create a S3 bucket in the af-south-1 (Cape Town) region using node.js aws-sdk, at version 2.726.0 (The latest at the time).

The region has been enabled and I am able to create a bucket using the management console. The IAM user I am using for debugging has full administrative access in the account.

My create bucket call is:

```
let res = await s3.createBucket({
  Bucket: 'bucketname',
  CreateBucketConfiguration: { LocationConstraint: 'af-south-1' }
}).promise();
```

This works for regions other than af-south-1.

In the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createBucket-property), a list of location constraints is given, is this list exhaustive of all possible options, or just a list of examples?

Is it possible to create a bucket in af-south-1 using the sdk, or am I doing something wrong?

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62045094/failing-to-create-s3-buckets-in-specific-regions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer AWS regions only support regional endpoints. Thus, if creating buckets in more than one region, a new instance of the S3 class needs to be created for each of the regions if you are using one of the newer regions:

```
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: 'af-south-1',
  });
```