# How to list all buckets in aws account of all regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have two buckets in my aws account. Both in different regions. When i'm trying to list them out using list_bucktes(), it only prints bucket of one region. Here is the code snippet:

```
s3=boto3.client("s3",aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
bucket_response=s3.list_buckets()

print(bucket_response)
```

I want it to print all buckets, irrespective of the region.

Comment: Then you need to iterate over all the available regions and perform a `list_buckets` in each.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list available regions with Boto3 (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451032/how-to-list-available-regions-with-boto3-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

S3 is not a region-based service, the API ListBuckets call does not even support any parameters. It always lists all the buckets in all the regions:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListBuckets.html#API_ListBuckets_RequestParameters

In boto3 it even says:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_buckets "Returns a list of all buckets owned by the authenticated sender of the request."

SOAP API
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPListAllMyBuckets.html

Can the problem be in that the sender is not the owner? For example that the bucket is shared with you from another account?

Comment: will look into this. Thanks